# Start a nodejs tcp server within nodejs app

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

My use case to start and stop a tcp server within the nodejs app that i am writing.

So I have an index.js which starts up a web server on port 3000. Using endpoints '/' and '/start', i would like to get the status of the server and start the server respectively. I would also like to display the status of the server via socket.io but that's for later.

Right now, I am getting a

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

error which I think it is probably attributable to returning the server object below.

How can I start and stop the tcp server via REST endpoints?

```
// server.js
'use strict'

var net = require('net')
var server = false

exports.get = function() {
    return server
}

exports.start = function(port, host) {

  if (!server) {
    server = net.createServer(handleConnection).listen(port, host)
    return server
  }
}

exports.stop = function() {
  if (server) {
    server.close(() => {
        console.log(`server.close called`)
    })
    server = null
    return server
  }
}

function handleConnection(socket) {
 ...
}
```

Here is the index.js

```
// index.js
'use strict'

var net = require('net')
var http = require('http')
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

var addServer = require('./server')

var PORT = 3000
var HOSTNAME = '127.0.0.1'

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

var server = http.createServer(app).listen(PORT, HOSTNAME, () => {
    console.log('http.createServer started')
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // get addServer status
  addServer.get()
  res.status(200).json({ status: 'success', command: addServer.get() })
})

app.get('/start', (req, res) => {
    // start addServer
    addServer.start(9000, '127.0.0.1')
    res.status(200).json({ status: 'success', response: '' })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to return server object via json.

```
res.status(200).json({ status: 'success', command: addServer.get() })
```

Try without it.

```
res.status(200).json({ status: 'success' })
```

Comment: how do i get the server to return it's up

Comment: I typed too quick, pls ignore the earlier comment. No, it's not it. addServer.get() returns a true or false.